# TextView on a map fragment does not follow its movement on dragging

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I am positioning a `TextView` on a Google Maps fragment like this:

```
private fun putTextView() {
    val layout : FrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout)
    val textView : TextView = TextView(this)
    textView.textSize = 14F
    textView.text = " some text "
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    textView.setPaddingRelative(100,100,0,0)
    layout.addView(textView)
}
```

It does appear where I want to it to appear, yet when I drag on the map, the `TextView` doesn't follow the movement but rather stays in the same place on the screen. How can I make it follow the movement of the map as I drag?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really just want a `Marker` with text, not a `TextView`. See the `IconGenerator` feature in the [android-maps-utils](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) library.